# How does one solve this TypeDoesNotContainType error?

Tags: psalm-php

This my code:

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
if ($sftp === false) {
```

This is the psalm error:

```
ERROR: TypeDoesNotContainType - src/MyFile.php:159:13 - resource does not contain false
        if ($sftp === false) {
```

..but the php manual says `ssh2_sftp` can return false:

> This method returns an SSH2 SFTP resource for use with all other
>   ssh2_sftp_*() methods and the ssh2.sftp:// fopen wrapper, or FALSE on
>   failure.

What am I missing here, or what am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug, you need to report it to Psalm developers here: https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/issues